# Reflection in java and attempting to replicate controller/action

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a way to get instantiate a class based on only string name? I understand reflection requires the package name o the fully qualified name. But if you were given:

/ClassName/methodName?argument=x

and you ripped that apart into something like:

`callClass(ClassName).callMethod(methodName).params(...)` (in this case `.params()` is for method)

In php this exceptionally easy. I understand this to be so easy in Java as the [docs state](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) that you need the fully qualified name of the class - as packages allow you to define a single name multiple times and that this kind of approach might lead to some serious performance issues.

Any ideas how I could achieve something like this

Comment: Nope, you need the fully qualified class name. Otherwise there is no way to identify which class method you want.

Comment: Also check out the javadocs of the various types involved in reflection, namely `Class` and `Method`. Unless the method is `static`, you need an instance of the class to invoke the method on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way or another, you need a fully qualified classname.

You could do this by convention - appending your classname to a predetermined package name (or assuming the default package)

Or, you could do some classloader magic to look up a full classname based on just the partial name (assuming the name is not ambiguous). In other words, your classloader would keep track of all loaded classes, then you could match against those classnames using your partial name.  This is seriously overkill for most applications, though.

Answer (score 0):

As the @DNA previously answered, you always need a fully qualified classname. Then comes the reflection, which both really slow and a total pain to deal with. With Guava for example, you could do something like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String myClassName = "App";
    String methodName = "method";
    Object[] params = {};
    ClassPath cp = ClassPath.from(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
    ImmutableSet<ClassPath.ClassInfo> cls = cp.getTopLevelClasses();

    for (ClassPath.ClassInfo cl : cls) {
        if(cl.getSimpleName().equals(myClassName)) {
            Class<?> clazz = cl.load();
            for (Method m : clazz.getMethods()) {
                if(m.getName().equals(methodName)) {
                    Object instance = clazz.newInstance();

                    // invoke method - prints Hello
                    m.invoke(instance, params);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void method() {
    System.out.println("Hello!!!");
}
```

Pretty atrocious. Throw a lot of exceptions you have to deal with. If you have a bigger project, using something like this will take ages.